# Reset EF migrations to clean slate - unique index not generated

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to reset migrations to a clean slate according to this guide:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jan/13/Resetting-Entity-Framework-Migrations-to-a-clean-Slate

The problem is that one DB table contains an unique index which was added in one of the migrations

```
CreateIndex("Localization_Resources", new string[] { "Culture", "Key" }, unique: true, name: "UX_Localization_Resources_Culture_Key");
```

and this index is not regenerated into the clean initial data migration when I run `add-migration Initial` according to the guide.
Why is this index not generated into the initial migration? How can it be solved? Thank you.

Comment: If it was not part of migration then you have to manually add the unique index using fluent API

Comment: I get it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was not part of migration then you have to manually add the unique index using fluent API like below example.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>()
            .HasIndex(b => b.PropertyName)
            .IsUnique();
```